# "Go" text with actionGO is still "GO" even Keyboard is arabic

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

**EditText** with **actionGO** and "GO" text is *displayed* even Keyboard is arabic

[image]

is this normal behavior? Can be changed to adapt the Keyboard language?

Comment: That will be up to the developers who implemented the keyboard. There are hundreds of keyboards. Hopefully most get the internationalization correct, but some will have bugs like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare said it is bug with keyboard.

As I after I remove my code that change label names, It starts to show strange texts on keyboard. I hope Samsung fix this issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the keyboard app that you are using. You can set the input type of the edit text by using the `android:inputType="blablabla"` attribute but this probably won't solve your problem.

Use other keyboard and check if the problem still exists.

Comment: how to use other keyboard, it is provided by user os

Comment: Download another keyboard application from the play store and change your default keyboard from the device settings. You might possibly find this setting under input section.

Comment: I develop app, so i can not force user of app to. download it from playstore

Comment: My friend this is not your fault you see, this is the problem in the keyboard you are using. That's why I said you to use another keyboard to check if the problem still persists!!